# Getting private key from .jks file

Tags: java, private-key, jks

I trying to get my private key from generated `.jks` file. But I'm getting this error, and i don't know how to fix it.

Here is a code for this program

```
    String jksFile = "C:/EDS/pb_3752709595.jks"; //path to file
    String password = "password";//pasword to jks file
    String alias=null; // alias

    // Load the keystore from file
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jksFile);
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(fis, password.toCharArray());

    // Get the aliases
    Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
    alias = aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println(alias);

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(jksFile), password.toCharArray());

    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias,password.toCharArray());//error line

    Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);

    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

   
   // System.out.println("Private key: " + privateKey);
    System.out.println("Public key: " + publicKey);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: excess private key
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:90)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1057)
    at Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

If anybody know how to deal with this issue, please help.
I have already tried to regenerate `.jks` file, but got the same error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

> The error message "java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: excess
> private key"

As per the exception, the keystore contains more than one private key, and the code is not specifying which key to retrieve.

```
// Get the aliases
Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
alias = aliases.nextElement();
```

Looking at the above code, it appears that the first alias returned by `keyStore.aliases()` is being used to retrieve the private key, without first checking if there are multiple aliases in the keystore.

```
// Get the aliases
Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String currentAlias = aliases.nextElement();
    if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(currentAlias)) {
        alias = currentAlias;
        break;
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, you can iterate through the aliases and choose the one that corresponds to the desired private key.

Here is an updated version of the code that should resolve the issue.

```
String jksFile = "C:/EDS/pb_3752709595.jks"; //path to file
String password = "password";//pasword to jks file
String alias = null; // alias

// Load the keystore from file
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jksFile);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
fis.close();

// Get the aliases
Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String currentAlias = aliases.nextElement();
    if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(currentAlias)) {
        alias = currentAlias;
        break;
    }
}

if (alias == null) {
    throw new Exception("No private key found in keystore.");
}

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

// Load the keystore again to prevent "excess private key" error
fis = new FileInputStream(jksFile);
keyStore.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
fis.close();

PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

System.out.println("Private key: " + privateKey);
System.out.println("Public key: " + publicKey);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The same issue